# stopping draggable function on scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this div called 'header'. which is draggable and has a scroll bar. to prevent the div dragging when clicking the srollbar I have this code below, however it is not effective if the thumb is at the absolute top and someone clicks the the top arrow or scrolls up with the thumb. it will then start to drag. same thing for the bottom. How can I prevent this from happening. Thanks.

```
$("#header").draggable({
    start: function() {
        if ($(this).data("scrolled")) {
            $(this).data("scrolled", false).trigger("mouseup");
            return false;
        }
    }
}).find("*").andSelf().scroll(function() {               

    $(this).parents(".ui-draggable").data("scrolled", true);

});
```

Comment: why so complex? just use 'cancel' option to disable dragging scrollbar. http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

Comment: I just used 'cancel' can't believe how simplified it made things. Thank you dude.

Comment: nice. i'm moving it to answer so that you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use 'cancel' option, you can solved it easily.

Please check their official doc
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel